# Auto Increment varchar in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Is there a way to set primary key auto increment, type of varchar in mySql?

Comment: What do you mean by auto-incrementing a varchar?

Comment: An auto increment field should be `INT`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455557/mysql-how-to-use-varchar-as-auto-increment-primary-key

Comment: Maybe you better look this link anyway, that a same question telling about.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699591/how-to-autoincrement-varchar

Comment: Check this [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699591/how-to-autoincrement-varchar) question in Stackoverflow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL - how to use VARCHAR as AUTO INCREMENT Primary Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455557/mysql-how-to-use-varchar-as-auto-increment-primary-key)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*NONE*. So far, `AUTO_INCREMENT` can be set for `INT` only. It needs to have your own logic to do that. eg,

- Get Last ID
- Get the INT part within the string
- Increment the value
- Concatenate
- Save to DB

Answer (score 0):

Duplication of [MySQL - how to use VARCHAR as AUTO INCREMENT Primary Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455557/mysql-how-to-use-varchar-as-auto-increment-primary-key)

According to my point of view you have to change it as integer type.
Since `AUTO_INCREMENT` is for `INT` type only, moreover setting the field as `PRIMARY KEY` which prevents duplication of values.

Answer (score 0):

AutoIncrement fields are integer in mysql.

You can mirror the auto-increment field in a varchar field and create a trigger which updates the varchar field on insert/update.

[Create Trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/create-trigger.html)

Answer (score 0):

for my experience, you can make Varcar ID as  auto increment but you must have logic..let say

```
 Dim crnum As String = "CR00001"
    Dim iTemp As Integer = 0

                iTemp = CInt(crnum.Substring(4, crnum.Length - 4)) '// get only the #'s from String and Convert them to Integer.
                iTemp += 1 '// increase the ID # + 1.
                crnum = crnum.Substring(0, 4) & iTemp.ToString("00000") '// set the ID back with String and #'s formatted to 5 digit #.
```

but you must do your own logic ,because after u run it for second time it will become duplicate primary key so, you must think your logic to apply your code. Anything is possible. ;)