# Can I insert data in an auto increment column?

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a database in MySQL which has a user_id that is primary key and auto incremented. Now my question is can I insert a static data in a column that is auto incremented? For example I want to insert a data "U-01" instead of just 1 only.

Comment: um, you can just concatenate it with the string of your liking you know

Comment: If you want insert "U-01" then the column be can't be integer, AUTO_INCREMENT can only be used on column types of integer!
Perhaps it gives a little workaround which is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038586/auto-increment-varchar-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column must be unauto increment, then you can insert this data!