# how to store auto increment id with string in mysql database

Tags: asp.net

i want to store auto increment id with string "SDMP" HOW TO DO THAT? when id increment it will be like SDMP1, SDMP2,....Like that

"Insert concat('SDMP', m_id) as id from merchant where m_id='" + id + "'";

I WANT TO SHOW DRIVER ID LIKE SDMP1 IN GRIDVIEW  BUT I WANT ID IN SDMP1 FORMAT

Comment: you want to update ID in the database as SDMP1 or just while display in the gridview column as SDMP1 ??

Comment: i want to store Auto increment ID with SDMP and after that search that id in gridview

Comment: If the code will always be SDMP then what's the point of it? It doesn't make it any more unique. You can't store that in an auto-increment column anyway. Just concatenate it on to the stored ID whenever you want to display it. You could do that either in a SQL select query or in some asp.net code

Comment: if you have solution please tel me i cant find out that solution i use MYSQL and i want query in mysql to store in database

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the existing table (where m_id is int and auto increment) then you can use this(before update query you need to change datatype of m_id)

```
ALTER TABLE merchant 
MODIFY COLUMN id varchar(50);
```

then use update query

```
UPDATE merchant set m_id=CONCAT("SDMP",m_id);
```

OR

If you want to insert m_id as SDMP1, SDMP2 autoincrement then you can use this

- Get Last ID
- Get the INT part within the string
- Increment the value
- Concatenate
- Save to DB

[moreinfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038586/auto-increment-varchar-in-mysql)

```
INSERT INTO merchant  
SELECT CONCAT("SDMP",SUBSTRING(m_id,5)+1),"abc4" 
FROM merchant order by m_id desc limit 1;
```

*NOTE: if no row in the DB then manually insert SDMP1 as the first row in DB*

OR

Keep thing simple, you keep `m_id as int auto_increment` in DB and while retrieving data from DB concat with SDMP `CONCAT("SDMP",m_id)`
and while searching in DB take integer part from gridview of m_id column

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195882/discussion-on-answer-by-mangesh-auti-how-to-store-auto-increment-id-with-string).