# Mysql - update with incrementing number into varchar

Tags: mysql

How to update names of the settlement that the first one will be "Castle 01", the next "Castle 02" and so on. The type of column village is varchar.

Something like this:

```
update settlement
set village = "Castle 01"  --next Castle 02, Castle 03,... Castle 12,...
```

Comment: Ordered how? What are the other columns in the table? Post enough info to understand your question.

Comment: vid as primary key int,
village varchar,
x int,
y int,
population int,
pid foreing key - reference table(player)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Auto Increment varchar in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038586/auto-increment-varchar-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Below sample code where you can update your input in a loop and make changes respectivily

```
declare @input nvarchar(100);
declare @count int=10
while(@count<100)
begin
 set @input=CONCAT('Castle ',@count);
 print(@input)  
 set @count=@count +1;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot auto-increment a `varchar` type column in mysql.

You can instead do one of the following:

1. Lookup existing records and get a `COUNT` then concatenate your varchar `village` to have both `castle` and the `value`. Perhaps using:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM settlement WHERE village LIKE 'Castle%';
```

2. Use two tables to define your `settlement types` and have an ID there instead, which will allow you to read your `settlements` back out with a join to then concatenate your `real` name.

If you do not do something similar to this on read/write then you'll keep running into having to update your column.