# How to make string auto increment

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got 2 different table:

**Table1**

```
ID
AK001 
AK001 
AK001
```

(above should be AK001, AK002, AK003 and so on....)

**Table2**

```
LastNum
 1
```

Table 1: update table1 set ID = xx + RIGHT('....'+()) and so on

Table 2: UPDATE table2 SET LastNum = LastNum + 1 (this works, but when I enter wrong detail when at create new form ,not yet save, its also give me +1)

my question is how to auto increment and update in Table 1 after Table 2 have been updated? Because what im facing is the table1 keep give me the same number when table2 is updated. Please help!

Comment: This may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455557/mysql-how-to-use-varchar-as-auto-increment-primary-key

Comment: Wich RDBMS are you using, MS SQL Server (version?), MySQL, Postgre, Oracle?

Comment: @Yaroslav i'm using sql server management studio

Comment: Having a plain `IDENTITY` column, and (if necessary) a computed column which adds the `AK` prefix would be far more sensible. If needs be, you can wrap that in a view that hides the identity column.

Comment: You just can't use AUTO_INCREMENT on a String type, can you?

Answer (score 3):

You should consider using INT as primary key and not a varchar. Then use that field as foreign key.

Here is a [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2103355/1297603) on why not to use VARCHAR as any type of key.

Keep storing yout store ID as varchar, just add new field on both tables, on the main one make sure to be IDENTITY, it would auto-increment.

There are many opinions on the subject about [using VARCHAR as primary key](https://www.google.com/search?q=using%20varchar%20as%20primary%20key). You should carefully analize the problem you are trying to solve. And ofcourse, maybe you just can't change anything and work with what already you have. On that case you need to use some work around as a trigger as suggested by @sgeddes.

Comment: if using INT, i can't store ID with string

Comment: @Bella: if **all** rows have the `AK` prefix, there is no need to store it.

Comment: Crappy design however you look at it. Using a business ID as a unique key - welcome to performance problems.

Comment: How does this really help answer the question?  Nothing to do with DB design/best practices...  Wow guys -- ganging up as usual I see...

Comment: Decide wich field should be the one to be used as PRIMARY KEY to avoid future performance/design problems... nothing to do with DB design best practices? Are you sure? And "ganging up as usual"? I really don't understand your point.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Table1 should always end with XXX which corresponds to the LastNum field in Table2, sounds like a `Trigger` would be most efficient.

Which RDBMS are you using?

If MySQL:

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger BEFORE INSERT ON Table2
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    //Here you should use NEW.Lastnum to UPDATE your Table1
    // update table1 set ID = xx + RIGHT('....'+())
  END;
```

SQL Server:

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger 
ON Table2
AFTER INSERT
AS
   //Here you should use INSERTED table (Lastnum column) to UPDATE your Table1
   // update table1 set ID = xx + RIGHT('....'+())
GO
```

You should be able to lookup other syntaxes that are RDBMS specific.

Good luck.

Comment: Just posted similar syntax -- let me know if you have trouble, pretty easy to write.  good luck.

Comment: Huh? :-)  Triggers run on a table after an action (insert, update, delete) is performed on that table.  Therefore, anytime an update to the lastnum column on table2 occurs, this trigger would run -- and in doing so, you could then update table1 with the new value -- make sense?