# Auto Increment in String Value

Tags: sql

I need query for auto increment in string value-

I need XS000001,XS000009....XS000099...XS000999,XS009999,XS099999,XS999999

Please help me...

Comment: further, I working on windows platform, using windows form application, I have one Addnew Insured button when I click on that it must create id between these range automatically. 

Thanks ...

Comment: If you are in windows app, why you want to handle in query.Store the latest value (say XS000010) then 'add 1 to 000010' and concatenate with 'XS'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434132/how-to-make-string-auto-increment

Answer (score 2):

If this is for **SQL Server** (you're not clear on which actual **database** you're using), the best solution is to use

- an `ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)` column to get SQL Server to handle the automatic increment of your numeric value
- a **computed, persisted** column to convert that numeric value to the value you need

So try this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable
  (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   AutoIncID AS 'XS' + RIGHT('000000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(6)), 6) PERSISTED,
   .... your other columns here....
  )
```

Now, every time you insert a row into `YourTable` without specifying values for `ID` or `AutoIncID`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)
VALUES (Val1, Val2, ....., ValN)
```

then SQL Server will **automatically and safely** increase your `ID` value, and `AutoIncID` will contain values like `XS000001`, `XS000002`,...... and so on - automatically, safely, reliably, no duplicates.

But the question really is: what if your number range is used up? What do you do *after* have handed out `XS999999` ? We cannot answer that for you .....

Comment: @RavindraBisht: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.