# How to generate autoincrement primary key in varchar

Tags: php, mysql

I want my UserId field to be like this AB001.

> Where AB is the name of anything and is constant,  and 001 is the
>   auto-increment value.

How can I do that in PHP and MySql.

Comment: You can find your Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893988/how-to-make-mysql-table-primary-key-auto-increment-with-some-suffix

Comment: i think you need to go for having a composite primary key, in which multiple fields together constitute a unique value. Then you can keep auto increment field separate from name and both fields will work together as primary key. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835978/how-to-properly-create-composite-primary-keys-mysql

Comment: @AmithRajShetty How can I implement that if I am using PHP and MySql??

Comment: if `AB` is constant and never changing you could just have a `view` on your table that exposes a column `ID`, but in the `select` of that view you would concatenate that constant value with a `normal` autoincrement like this `SELECT 'AB' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10)) AS ID FROM yourTable`

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can increment the var like this:

```
$var = "AB001";

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo $var . "\n";
    $var++;
}
```

Then you just need to insert it into mysql...

EDIT ----

However you may encounter ID collisions if two processes create the same ID at the same time!

Another Edit ----

You could make a function like this and pass in the DB ID and the base format like this:

```
$base = "AB000";

echo createId($base, 1456);

function createId($base, $dbId)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < $dbId; $i++) {
        $base++;
    }
    return $base;
}
```

I hope this is what your looking for :)

Comment: is this really valid php? you declare `$i` in the loop but never use it and then you `increment $var` which has been assigned to a string... that works?

Comment: `$i` is used in the loop to check that it is lower than 10 after each iteration

Comment: I am giving a user this UserId when he registers. The attribute in table is A_I.

Comment: @micb yea i take that back didn't work with php for a long time, seems it works (http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ifq-1jd) but still i would really not recommend to do this id retrieving thing in php, but rather in the database itself since it can take care of uniqueness and stuff way better (not to mention it indeed CAN take care of those things whilst php cannot :D)

Comment: DrCopyPaste I agree... @user3220816 ok i think i get what your after, I will update my response in a min

Comment: @micb Isn't there any other way to do that in database itself??

Comment: @user3220816 with a composite key you could, as mentioned earlier in the comments: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5836070/2186023

Comment: you could maybe create a stored procedure in mysql, but im not sure how to do those. As 'Daniel Bottner' said you can do it at run time, the method above will allow you to do that. You would be decorating the ID on every call, or perhaps you could create a cache of them so that you don't have to recreate them each time, although im not sure they will take that long to create until you get to a very high ID

Answer (score 0):

Please read following questions:

- [how-to-make-string-auto-increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434132/how-to-make-string-auto-increment)
- [mysql-how-to-use-varchar-as-auto-increment-primary-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455557/mysql-how-to-use-varchar-as-auto-increment-primary-key)

You could also try to use [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/triggers.html) if you really depend on having this field in the database.

Otherwise build the AB part at run time to show it to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ed88/1). Let me know if you need any more clarifications.

Comment: this short of a text would have better been a comment. Don't just link stuff in your answer, please include the relevant explanations and code in your answer; so it is not reliant on external resources ;)

Comment: I cannot comment as I donot have enough reputations(min 50) to comment on a question.

Comment: then expand your answer ;) It should not be necessary to call links to understand an answer; using fiddle is fine but include your code here so one does not rely on that

Comment: from next time.. :) I thought providing a working example where people can edit the code would be more helpful to understand. :)

Comment: I would always encourage to do so, but I also would always encourage to include explanation about that, too (obviously a working code example WITH explanations is more helpful than one without ;))